# Is a single server setup appropriate for this high volume Rails/Mongo application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb, nginx, scalability

I'm building the backend of an IOS/Android app in Rails, hosted with Nginx, passenger and mongo as a database.

The apps will communicate with the backend via JSON, but 99% of the calls will be simple GET requests to read data. I intend on caching the JSON data in flat files, and serving them directly through Nginx, so almost no traffic will be actually hitting the server. The files will also be extremely small in nature, and will not be larger than 5-10KB.

However, I am expecting a high volume of concurrent users (several hundred to several thousand), so I want to know if a powerful single server setup (e.g. 8 GB RAM, 4 cores) would be suitable for this, if Nginx is configured to server the cached JSON assets, with only a select few requests hitting the backend.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to find out: test it! Setup a test server, use something like Apache bench (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html), jmeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) or other testing services/tools. There is really no other way to tell if your setup will work.

Overall, yes, it *sounds* like this setup will work considering you will serve the files via Nginx, which is quite fast.